# Get unique date from timestamps using h2 or hsqldb

Tags: h2, hsqldb

I can get the result I want using
`SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(loginTimeStamp)) FROM login;` in mySQL, how to do the same using h2 database or hsqldb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [`FORMATDATETIME`](http://FORMATDATETIME) function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    FORMATDATETIME(loginTimeStamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
FROM login;
```

Or, try casting your timestamp column to a date:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CAST(loginTimeStamp AS DATE)
FROM login;
```